# How can I serialise a variable but not deserialise it with the Simple serialisation framework?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I currently use SimpleXML on Android to serialise an immutable object to an XML file.

I want to deserialise this object using constructor injection.

However, not all my `@Element` annotated variables are passed as parameters to my constructor, since some are derived (and set in the constructor, based on the other parameters). Therefore a `ConstructorException` is thrown upon serialisation: "no constructor accepts all read only values".

Is there any way I can ensure SimpleXML outputs my derived variable to the XML file (the derived variable is based on fairly complex calculations), but doesn't attempt to read and set that derived variable?

Comment: Even after adding an extra constructor to accept (and then ignore) the variables I will calculate for myself, I'm getting PersistenceException - "Constructor not matched for class".

Comment: Setting required=false on the optional constructor arguments did the trick.

Comment: Setting required=false is now not required for constructor arguments - this turned out to be a bug that was subsequently fixed in Simple 2.6.5.